# php mkdir via symlink warning

Tags: php, symlink, mkdir

I want to make directory recursively by use of symlinks (softlinks) but I encouter with warning :

> Warning:  mkdir(): File exists in ...Path to php code... on line 21

The directory that i want to create is `/vagrant/resources/page`.

In the `/var/www` path I create a symlink named `resources` that links to `/vagrant/resources` directory and the php code is like below:

```
$directory = '/var/www/resources/page';
if(!file_exists($directory)){
      mkdir($directory,0777,true);
}
```

The permissions to all directories inside /vagrant is set to 777.
Thanks.

Comment: The warning message is clear: the directory to be created already exists. Note however, that a _warning_ is not an _error_. Probably the script just claims (correctly), that `/var`, `/var/www`, `/var/www/resources` already exists...

Comment: Another thing, just a general hint: a file system permission of 0777 _never_ is a good idea and typically not required. You reduce the security of your system here. _Why?_

Answer (score 0):

As @arkascha mentioned your problem is not with symlinks but with the existence of the directory you are trying to make. which is a bit strange considering you have a fair condition around your mkdir command.

have try with `is_dir()` instead of `file_exists()`

Comment: I tested is_dir and the problem not solved. When I try to make directory from main path (`/vagrant`) everything is ok but from the symlink (`/var/www`) path no sub-directory  created.With this code mkdir not working : 
`$directory = '/var/www/resources/widgets/mysite/_html_pages/categories/Calendar.html/Calendar.html/';
$file = $directory . 'Calendar.html___1435404786.html';
        $content = 'test content.';
        if(!is_dir($directory)){
            mkdir($directory,0777,true);
        }
        file_put_contents($file, $content);` but when I use `/vagrant` instead of `/var/www` it's ok.

Comment: Strange, your code is working fir me, only different is i'm making a symlink of my Music folder in the tmp. What is the OS you are using? is the filesystem case sensitive? and if so, are you sure you are using the exact case for the symlink?

Comment: Dear Ali, I'm using virtual box and vagrant tools and my OS is ubuntu 12.04. After much effort I run the symlink command again and the problem fixed. `sudo ln -s /vagrant/resources/* /var/www/resources`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem with readlink. Also checking before if it is a link or not. After than the path can be used as expected.

```
$path = '/var/www/resources'
if (is_link($path)) {
    $path = readlink($path);
}
```